# Ubuntu won't detect Windows 10 during installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Ubuntu 18.04 won't find Windows 10 UEFI. There is no "Install alongside Windows Bootloader" option. I have to keep UEFI on so I can boot to Windows 10.

Comment: Are you booting the Ubuntu install media in UEFI mode?  Mode depends upon the UEFI/BIOS settings, the install media has both.

Comment: Make sure fast start up is off. And note that Windows updates will turn it back on, and then grub will not boot Windows. You have to boot directly from UEFI boot menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions